# Is this the best way to add Font Awesome icons into header.links - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Will this work?

```
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> 
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</argument>
```

EDIT - I am trying to add font awesome icons into the header.panel and footer. Thanks to comments here, I added phtml templates into the blocks in the default.xml, referenced the correct containers and now the custom ul>li>a are rendering. However the font awesome i class and icons wont show. The cdn is loading (checked in chrome developer) and I set a width and height to the .fa class. still they aren't appearing.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting. How did you get it to accept the elements?

Comment: Hi, could you please update your question with some more information like: which file(s) are you editing? How did you include the font-awesome font to the site etc?

Comment: Yes, I was editing <vendor><theme> -> Magento_Theme -> layout -> default.xml. I added font awesome into default_head_blocks.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this won't work. You cannot mix HTML code with XML code in a layout `default.xml` file.

In `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml` you can see for example how the header links are added:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The `customer.phtml` template file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <span class="customer-name"
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
            <button type="button"
                    class="action switch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change')?></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php if($block->getChildHtml()):?>
        <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, the CSS classes are added there.

### How to add the fontawsome CSS classes

The easiest thing would be to override these files (for example `account/customer.phtml` and add the fontawesome css class tags in these templates. You have to copy the `account/customer.phtml` to your own theme and adjust the css classes there. Do not overwrite coure files :-)

Comment: Nah, this didn't help me out unfortunately. I need to apply fa classes to li.nav.item.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only place I can find on a default Magento install with the luma theme for `li.nav.item` is in the footer links. Is this is where you want to place the icons? If not, where are you looking to place them? It will change the answer you need.

Comment: Could you please update your question or add some more details what exactly you want to change @Azul_Falcone?

Comment: I added this to my Magento_Theme default.xml               `<referenceContainer name="header.panel">                            <container name="social_header" htmlClass="header links" htmlTag="ul" before="contact-us">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="social.header" template="Magento_Theme::html/social-header.phtml"/></container></referenceContainer>`

Comment: Is post updated on how you solved it?  Can you post your answer here please?  I have similar question.